# Any Javascript Code to Unfreeze Browser if it hangs in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue where i am using simple html file upload. The Issue is that, whenever i click on the browse  button the entire window freezes for sometime. Also there are no events binded to this file input. So i was doing research on this issue,meanwhile is there anyway we can write a javascript or jquery code to keep a track of screen freeze and unfreeze the screen automatically as a workaround?

I am using jquery plugins like jquery(3.1v),jquery ui(1.8.x),jquery.validate(1.8.x).

Also i am attaching a screen shot of the freeze issue on click of browse
[image: f it]

As you can see, on click of browse button, file dialog box is not shown instead entire IE11 browser hangs!

**Note : This issue appears only on IE11 and on other browsers like chrome, edge works fine**
below is the code i tried?

```
<input type="file"/>

$(document).ready(function() {
var time = new Date().getTime();
    $(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
        time = new Date().getTime();
    });

    function refresh() {
        if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 60000) 
            window.location.reload(true);
        else 
            setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
    }

    setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
});
```

The above JS code works if screen is not in freezed state. I have to go to the TaskManager to kill the IE11 and start afresh!

Please let me know your inputs?

Comment: I don't think the code you posted is the cause of the browser hanging.

Comment: "*As you can see, on click of browse button*" - no, I can't *see* that

Comment: Javascript runs in a single-thread.  If the browser is stuck, so is the javascript thread.  You'll need to know the cause of the hang to know if javascript is also blocked, but the chances of javascript still running when the rest of the browser is frozen are 0.

Comment: eg if you do `while (1) { ; }` then javascript will get stuck and you won't be able to run any other javascript.  Timeouts etc run when the current method has finished, they don't "interupt" running code.  If javascript *is* causing the freeze, then the browser should ask if you want to cancel long-running process (even crappy old IE11 has this, whether it works or not is another matter).  So it's likely not javascript causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot unfreeze the browser via javascript, unless it's your script that causes the freeze. When IE is frozen, the part of IE that is responsible for running JS is frozen too. Even if JS was running and frozen, timeouts and mouse events would not trigger.

Most likely, the freezing is browser bug related to one of the Windows Explorer DLL extensions - a problem in your installation. Or it's an IE bug. Either way, there isn't anything you can do about it as a website designer. Try it on another computer. Run IE wit addons off.

Or just write on the website that IE is not supported.